# How to use Clutter.ShaderEffect.set_uniform_value() properly?

Tags: clutter, gjs

I am trying set a `uniform float` of a `Clutter.ShaderEffect`. This works well if floating point Numbers are passed to `set_uniform_value()`. However, when you pass an integer Number, an OpenGL  error (1282, Invalid operation) is thrown. It seems that the implementation assumes in this case that the uniform is actually of type `int`. Here is a minimal example:

```js
const {Clutter, GObject} = imports.gi;

Clutter.init(null);

let stage  = new Clutter.Stage({width: 200, height: 200});
let shader = new Clutter.ShaderEffect({shader_type: Clutter.ShaderType.FRAGMENT_SHADER});

shader.set_shader_source(`
  uniform float value;

  void main(void) {
    cogl_color_out = vec4(value, 0, 0, 1);
  }
`);

// This creates the OpenGL Error.
// shader.set_uniform_value('value', 1);

// This works however:
shader.set_uniform_value('value', 0.999);

stage.add_effect(shader);

stage.connect('destroy', () => Clutter.main_quit());
stage.show();

Clutter.main();
```

So how do I force `set_uniform_value()` to interpret the value as floating point number? Reading the documentation (https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter6~6_api/clutter.shadereffect#method-set_uniform_value), I would assume that I could pass a `GObject.Value` - maybe like this:

```js
let value = new GObject.Value();
value.init(GObject.TYPE_FLOAT);
value.set_float(1.0);
shader.set_uniform_value('value', value);
```

But this yields the error `Invalid uniform of type 'GValue' for name 'value'`. Maybe I now have a `GObject.Value` containing a `GObject.Value` containing a `GObject.TYPE_FLOAT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of GJS 1.68.0 (GNOME 40), passing a GObject.Value works:

```
let value = new GObject.Value();
value.init(GObject.TYPE_FLOAT);
value.set_float(1);
shader.set_uniform_value('value', value);
```

Answer (score 1):

**if someone looks for this question, I have the answer**:

[https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter7~7_api/clutter.shadereffect#method-set_uniform_value](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter7%7E7_api/clutter.shadereffect#method-set_uniform_value) *value - a GObject.Value GObject.TYPE_FLOAT for float*

and in gjs GTK Javascript they have [https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter7~7_api/clutter.value_set_shader_float](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/clutter7%7E7_api/clutter.value_set_shader_float)

`value_set_shader_float(value,[float])` method - *Value must have been initialized using %CLUTTER_TYPE_SHADER_FLOAT.*

and in Javascript version of GTK they dont have any way to initialize that *CLUTTER_TYPE_SHADER_FLOAT* or *GObject.TYPE_FLOAT*

**The solution is**:

```
function make_float(val) {
    return Math.floor(val)==val?val+0.000001:val;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it a solution, it's rather a workaround. What happens if there are cases where you want the integer value in the shader? For example, you cannot pass a zero this way which might be important in some cases. Btw, you could also use `return Number.isInteger(val) ? val+0.0000001 : val` which I think is more readable.